# How to draw image with colormap in MS Chart or other .Net chart component?

Tags: .net, image, charts, color-mapping

How to programatically create image with colormap like the picture below? Color are different in each rectangle to present different value based on color-mapping.

Tried to do it with MS Chart, but no satisfied results. Can manage to create with Point, Stacked Colomn, rectangle annotation. But all got performance issue when rendering thousands of columns.

How to render it with MS chart or other chart components available for .Net?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After more experiments, I did not find efficient way to visualize color image with existing MS Chart types. I finally implement image display with Graphics Bitmap, then display Bitmap as image on MS Chart, to overcome performance issue.